# Ability to calculate difference between time between two different rows in a table using SQL query

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I am trying to find a way to determine amount of time between two separate rows in a table.
for example, my table has user, date and time stamp , transaction type

example of data:

```
Joe    10/2/2020 9:01:30     Shipping
Joe    10/2/2020 9:01:55     Shipping
Joe   10/02/2020 9:05:30     Shipping
```

I would like to see in my output

```
user      date/time               time difference
 Joe    10/2/2020 9:01:30
Joe    10/2/2020 9:01:55          25 seconds
Joe   10/02/2020 9:05:30        3 min 35 seconds
```

The end goal would be to have different transaction type and find out how long the user worked at each transaction type, I only have the endtime to work with.

Comment: You should update your question to make clear what database server you intend on using.

Answer (score 1):

**For MYSQL Server Version 8+**

If you are using a recent version of MySQL Server like version 8.0, you can try to use the **LAG() function**.

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkLog (
    employee_name varchar(10),
    Shipping_Time DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_name, Shipping_Time)
);
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Joe","2020-10-02 12:00:00.000");
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Joe","2020-10-02 12:01:30.000");
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Joe","2020-10-02 12:05:30.000");
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Joe","2020-10-02 12:10:00.000");
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Joe","2020-10-02 12:20:00.000");

INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Sue","2020-10-02 12:00:00.000");
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Sue","2020-10-02 12:01:30.000");
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Sue","2020-10-02 12:05:30.000");
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Sue","2020-10-02 12:10:00.000");
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES("Sue","2020-10-02 12:20:00.000");
```

**SQL Query - to get result as Seconds:**

```
SELECT employee_name,
Shipping_Time,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, (LAG(Shipping_Time,1) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_name)),Shipping_Time) AS TimeDiffInSeconds
FROM WorkLog
ORDER BY employee_name, Shipping_Time;
```

Output:

```
| employee_name | Shipping_Time       | TimeDiffInSeconds |
| ------------- | ------------------- | ----------------- |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:00:00 |                   |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:01:30 | 90                |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:05:30 | 240               |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:10:00 | 270               |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:20:00 | 600               |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:00:00 |                   |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:01:30 | 90                |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:05:30 | 240               |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:10:00 | 270               |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:20:00 | 600               |
```

**SQL Query - to get result as Time (hh:mm:ss):**

```
SELECT employee_name,
Shipping_Time,
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, (LAG(Shipping_Time,1) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_name)),Shipping_Time)) AS "TimeDiff hh:mm:ss"
FROM WorkLog
ORDER BY employee_name, Shipping_Time;
```

Output:

```
| employee_name | Shipping_Time       | TimeDiff hh:mm:ss |
| ------------- | ------------------- | ----------------- |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:00:00 |                   |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:01:30 | 00:01:30          |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:05:30 | 00:04:00          |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:10:00 | 00:04:30          |
| Joe           | 2020-10-02 12:20:00 | 00:10:00          |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:00:00 |                   |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:01:30 | 00:01:30          |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:05:30 | 00:04:00          |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:10:00 | 00:04:30          |
| Sue           | 2020-10-02 12:20:00 | 00:10:00          |
```

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag

---

**For MS SQL Server**

Using new information from OP's comments:

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE JSSHIPMENTTABLE (
    CREATEDBY varchar(10),
    CREATEDDATETIME DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME)
);
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Joe','2020-10-02 12:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Joe','2020-10-02 12:01:30.000');

INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Sue','2020-10-02 12:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Sue','2020-10-02 12:01:30.000');

INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Sam Colton','2020-10-01 12:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Sam Colton','2020-10-01 12:01:30.000');
INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Sam Colton','2020-10-01 12:05:30.000');
INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Sam Colton','2020-10-01 12:10:00.000');
INSERT INTO JSSHIPMENTTABLE(CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME) VALUES('Sam Colton','2020-10-01 12:20:00.000');
```

**MS SQL Server Query - to get result as Seconds:**

```
SELECT CREATEDBY,
CREATEDDATETIME,
datediff(second,(lag(CREATEDDATETIME,1) over (PARTITION by CREATEDBY ORDER BY CREATEDDATETIME)),CREATEDDATETIME) as TimeDiffinSeconds
from JSSHIPMENTTABLE
where convert(date,CREATEDDATETIME,23) = '2020-10-01' and CREATEDBY like '%Colton%' order by CREATEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME
```

Output:

```
CREATEDBY   CREATEDDATETIME              TimeDiffinSeconds
----------------------------------------------------------
Sam Colton  2020-10-01 12:00:00.000      NULL
Sam Colton  2020-10-01 12:01:30.000      90
Sam Colton  2020-10-01 12:05:30.000      240
Sam Colton  2020-10-01 12:10:00.000      270
Sam Colton  2020-10-01 12:20:00.000      600
```

Comment: I am rather new to SQL please forgive my ignorance.  I am using SQL server management studio version 15.0.  I tried the above, but it did like the command timestampdiff, so I changed it to datediff and that seemed to work but when I run the command I am getting an error:

Comment: Here is my command: select CREATEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,datediff(second,(lag(createddatetime,1) over (PARTITION by createdby)),CREATEDDATETIME) as timediffinseconds 
from JSSHIPMENTTABLE where convert(date,CREATEDDATETIME,23) = '2020-10-01' and CREATEDBY like '%Colton%'
order by CREATEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME

Comment: Getting the following error:  MSG 4112, Level 15, Stat1, Line 1  The function 'lag' must hve an OVER clause with the order by

Comment: For anyone else reading this later I have updated the answer to include MS SQL Server specific samples at the bottom.

Comment: OMG, amazing this worked perfectly and so fast!  Thank you!  :)

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. Kindly mark this as your accepted answer IF you feel it has addressed your original query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query out. You can edit the DATEDIFF function to give you the difference in minutes, hours, days, or whatever increment you would like.

```
SELECT a.user, a.[date/time], DATEDIFF(second, b.[date/time], a.[date/time]) AS [time difference]
FROM #YourTable a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #YourTable b
    WHERE a.user = b.user
    AND b.[date/time] < a.[date/time]
    ORDER BY [date/time] DESC
) b
ORDER BY a.user, a.[date/time] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Sample Table:
CREATE TABLE WorkLog (
    employee_name varchar(10),
    Shipping_Time DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_name, Shipping_Time)
);

-- Sample Data:
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES('Joe','2020-10-02 12:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES('Joe','2020-10-02 12:01:30.000');
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES('Joe','2020-10-02 12:05:30.000');
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES('Joe','2020-10-02 12:10:00.000');
INSERT INTO WorkLog(employee_name, Shipping_Time) VALUES('Joe','2020-10-02 12:20:00.000');

Select *, 
FORMAT(Shipping_Time - LAG(Shipping_Time) OVER (ORDER BY employee_name), 'mm:ss') As timeDiference
From WorkLog
Order By Shipping_Time ASC

-- Results:
employee_name   Shipping_Time   timeDiference
Joe 2020-10-02  12:00:00.000    NULL
Joe 2020-10-02  12:01:30.000    01:30
Joe 2020-10-02  12:05:30.000    04:00
Joe 2020-10-02  12:10:00.000    04:30
Joe 2020-10-02  12:20:00.000    10:00
```

Comment: This did work, the only issue was I did not get NULL on the first one?  I did add a where a clause:  SELECT a.createdby, a.CREATEDDATETIME, DATEDIFF(second, b.createddatetime, a.CREATEDDATETIME) AS timediff
FROM JSSHIPMENTTABLE a  
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM JSSHIPMENTTABLE b
    WHERE a.createdby = b.CREATEDBY
    AND b.CREATEDDATETIME < a.CREATEDDATETIME
 
    ORDER BY CREATEDDATETIME DESC
) b
where a.CREATEDBY like '%Colton.J%' and  convert(date,a.CREATEDDATETIME,23) = '2020-10-01'   
ORDER BY a.CREATEDBY, a.CREATEDDATETIME ASC

Comment: Here was my first line in the output:  createdby CREATEDDATETIME timediff
Colton.J 2020-10-01 12:11:59.000 143588  instead of Null I got 143588.  I can probably work around this...Thank you